# Deleting model's file attachments on forceDelete() - OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

I have a model with many attachments and soft delete enabled:

```php
public $attachMany = [
    'gallery' => 'System\Models\File',
];
```

If I add `softDelete => true` to the `'gallery'` array above, it deletes gallery images from the disk after the soft delete, however I'd like to have image attachments deleted from the disk only when I permanently delete the model (`forceDelete()`).

Model's event `afterDelete()` appears to be triggered also after the soft delete, so it doesn't seem that I could use that either.

How do I get the gallery images deleted from the disk only when I force delete the model?

**Addition:**

For some reason this doesn't delete images nor records of them either:

```php
public function trashed_onDelete()
{
    $ids = post('checked');
    $items = MyModel::onlyTrashed()->whereIn('id', $ids);

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        foreach ($item->gallery as $image) {
            $image->delete();
        }
    }

    $items->forceDelete();
}
```

Comment: can you share one thing first?
1. you are deleting the main model means model which contain "attachMany" relation or related gallery items
2. can you also check that related records are also deleted from the database or not, means `gallery images deleted from the disk` -> this has DB records as well those records are deleted or not

Comment: 1) Yes, the model I'm deleting has *attachMany* relation as well as images attached to it. 2) When I indicate `softDelete => true` in the `attachMany = ['gallery' => ...]`, then the images are deleted from the disk as well as their records deleted from the db - this is exactly the behavior I want on `forceDelete()`, instead of on soft delete as it's now, because in case the soft deleted model is eventually restored, the attached images are not there anymore.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info I will look into it :)

Comment: if I change `softDelete => true` to just `delete => true`, then nothing happens when I soft and force delete a model with attached images, the orphaned images remain on the disk and records of them remain in database.

Comment: hmm, sorry I am lately a little busy so could not check the issue once I get time I will surely check it out and give you a proper fix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `System\Models\File` model does not have `SoftDelete trait` and `deleted_at field` so it will not act as other models.

For now, you need to manage this kind of relation manually.

> What you can do?

1. just **do NOT** add any kind of option `softDelete => true` OR `delete => true`
2. when you `soft delete` your main model than all the related `gallery files` will `not be deleted` as its expected, and when you restore main model all `gallery files` will be there.
3. Now when you perform `forceDelete()` you need need to add additional code in your main model like below to `actually delete` those relations.

```php
<?PHP

//... your model

public $attachMany = [
    'gallery' => 'System\Models\File',
];

public function afterDelete() {
    // it will ensure that your file model is deleted. 
    // once parent model is actually deleted
    foreach ($this->gallery as $gallery) {
        $gallery->delete();
    }
}

//.. your model
```

Ref: https://octobercms.com/forum/post/deleting-attachments-when-deleting-model

if any doubt then, please comment.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question: *model's event `afterDelete()` appears to be triggered also after the soft delete, so it doesn't seem that I could use that either.*

Comment: I've added some more info to my question just now

Comment: hmm I will check in more details My after delete was not fired if I soft delete main records, or may be I overlooked let me check them once again.